# Linq anonymous type with list object property

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, anonymous-types

I have an object lets say its classrooms that is returned from the repository but I use an anonymous type for my View so I convert it like so

```
 return from P in db.ClassRooms
               where P.LocationId == LocationId && P.IsApproved==true
               select new ClassRoomsViewModel
               {
                   Id = P.Id,
                   Created = P.CreatedOn,
                   IsApproved = P.IsApproved,
                   IsDeleted = P.IsDeleted,
                   Desks = ??
               }
```

the problem is I am not sure how to handle the desk object.

In my ClassRoomsViewModel class Desks is a list object

```
public class ClassRoomsViewModel{

   public long Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime Created { get; set; }
   public List<DeskViewModel> Desks { get; set; }

 }
   public class DeskViewModel{

   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
 }
```

The classrooms dataobject is link as a reference to the Desk Object.
so from the above linq query P.Desks.Name will return the name of all objects in the classroom for the linq query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the collection of desks from the data model, convert each one to a `DeskViewModel`, and convert the resulting sequence to a `List<T>`.

That would look something like

```
p.Desks.Select(d => new DeskViewModel { ... }).ToList()
```

Comment: so like : Desks=p.Desks.Select(d => new DeskViewModel { ... }).ToList() ?

Comment: Thanks. It compiles like it works perfectly. Hopefully it runs smoothly

Answer (score 0):

If P.Desks.Name and P.Desks.Id are arrays you could do it like this with zip.

```
return from P in db.ClassRooms
           where P.LocationId == LocationId && P.IsApproved==true
           select new ClassRoomsViewModel
           {
               Id = P.Id,
               Created = P.CreatedOn,
               IsApproved = P.IsApproved,
               IsDeleted = P.IsDeleted,
               Desks = P.Desks.Name.Zip(P.Desks.Id,
                           (n, i) => new DeskViewModel { Id = i, Name = n });
           }
```